# How to avoid race condition when refcounting without a mutex?

Tags: c++, atomic, lock-free

I'm trying to figure out how to avoid the race condition in the following code, with thread A acquiring the datablock, then thread B Releasing/deleting it, and then thread A AddRefing it.  Is it possible to fix this without a mutex? I think that it's possible to fix this with atomic_thread_fence, but I really have no idea how it would apply to this situation.

```
#include <atomic>

class Foo
{
    std::atomic<Datablock*> datablock

public:
    Datablock * get_datablock()
    {
        Datablock * datablock = m_datablock.load();
        if(datablock) datablock->AddRef();
        return datablock;
    }

    void set_datablock(Datablock* datablock)
    {
        datablock = m_datablock.exchange(datablock);
        if(datablock) datablock->Release();
    }
};
```

Comment: This isn't an ABA problem. (The value changes from A to B, but not back to A.) This is a general race condition. Can you use a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: I'm trying to learn lock-free programming starting from the simplest cases; and this is the most basic one i could think of, so using `shared_ptr` would defeat the purpose of that.

Comment: `atomic_thread_fence` is only useful if you're using memory orderings weaker than the default `seq_cst` (see http://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/ for more about fences.  Jeff Preshing's articles are *excellent*; definitely read most of those while you're trying to grok lockless programming).  And BTW, it would be a good idea to fix your example so it compiles; e.g. declare the member as `m_datablock` and add a missing semicolon.  (http://gcc.godbolt.org/ is nice for testing snippets).

Comment: This looks equivalent to [atomic_shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/atomic_shared_ptr). AFAIK it is possible to write a lockfree implementation, but not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that it's possible to fix this with atomic_thread_fence

`atomic_thread_fence` is only useful if you're using memory orderings weaker than the default `seq_cst` (see [Jeff Preshing's article about C++11 fences](http://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/) for more about fences and memory ordering. Jeff Preshing's articles are excellent; definitely read most of those while you're trying to grok lockless programming).

`atomic_thread_fence` can only limit reordering of how the current thread's memory operations become globally visible.  It doesn't itself wait for something in other threads.

---

**When you try to add a reference, be prepared to find that it had already dropped to zero**.  i.e. `AddRef()` can fail, if you were too late and another thread has already started to destroy the refcounted object.

So the implementation of AddRef would do something like

```
bool AddRef() {
    int old_count = m_refcount;

    do {
        if (old_count <= 0) {
            // we were too late; refcount had already dropped to zero
            // so another thread is already destroying the data block
            return false;
        }
    }while( !m_refcount.compare_exchange_weak(old_count, old_count+1) );

    return true;
}
```

We're using a CAS loop as a conditional `fetch_add` instead of doing a `fetch_add` and then *un*doing it if the old value was too low.  The latter would require extra work to avoid a race condition if *two* threads were incrementing at once.  (The 2nd thread would see and old_count of 1 and think it was ok.)  You could maybe work around that by having the `Release` function set the refcount to a large negative number *before* starting to destroy a block, but this is easy to verify and a CAS that almost always succeeds on the first try is barely any slower than an actual `fetch_add`.  The separate atomic load is nearly free compared to CAS, especially on x86.  (You could use `memory_order_relaxed` for it to make it near-free on weakly-ordered architectures too.)

---

**Note that your refcount can't be part of the datablock that you `delete` when the refcount reaches zero**.  If you did that, a thread that called `get_datablock` and did `m_datablock.load()`, then slept, then dereferenced that pointer with `datablock->AddRef()` could segfault (or cause other undefined behaviour) if the pointed-to memory was deleted by another thread while it was asleep.

---

This answer is doesn't solve the *whole* problem (of managing refcount blocks while still allowing an `exchange` in your `set_datablock` API.  I'm not sure that API design really works.

It's also not a complete working [`atomic_shared_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/atomic_shared_ptr) implementation.

If you want to know how that works, look at its documents, or hopefully someone's written a post about how it's implemented.  Open-source library implementations of it exist, but are probably pretty hard to read.